# Changing the background color of a specific item in list view depending upon some conditions

Tags: android, parse-platform

i am developing a instant chat application using parse back end and Sinch service.In my application ListUsersActivity is there in which i am fetching all the users from parse back end and i am displaying it this is working fine.And in parse back end i am storing each message with one Boolean field READ with false value means the message is in unread state and sender id and recipient id .

Now what i want to do is while displaying users if any unread messages are there with specific user i want to highlight that user so that notify some unread messages are there.

to achieve this i tried following till now..

```
public class ListUsersActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private String currentUserId;
private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> names;
private ListView usersListView;
private Button logoutButton;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;
private Boolean Net;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_users);
     //showSpinner();
}
//display clickable a list of all users
private void setConversationsList() {
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, com.parse.ParseException  e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                    names.add(userList.get(i).getUsername().toString());
                    String userId =  userList.get(i).getObjectId().toString();

                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseMessage");
                    query.whereEqualTo("read", false);
                    query.whereEqualTo("senderId", userId);
                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> messageList,  ParseException e) {
                            if(e == null){
                                namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  (getApplicationContext(),R.layout.newmessage,names);
                            }

                        }
                    });


                }
                usersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);


                usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);
                  usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i,  long l) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(i);
                            openConversation(names, i);
                        }
                        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e1){
                            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
//open a conversation with one person
public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {

    Net=isNetworkAvailable();
        if(Net) {
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.whereEqualTo("username", names.get(pos));
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                public void done(List<ParseUser> user,   com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),   MessagingActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID",   user.get(0).getObjectId());
                        intent.putExtra("name", user.get(0).getUsername());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error finding that user",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"No internet or   slow",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}

//show a loading spinner while the sinch client starts
private void showSpinner() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Boolean success = intent.getBooleanExtra("success", false);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (!success) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Messaging service   failed to start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new   IntentFilter("com.moborder.anil.commoner.ListUsersActivity"));
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    setConversationsList();
    super.onResume();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager)   getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo =   connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

}
```

I crated two xml files for items of litview 
 1 .newmessage.xml with pink background color.
 2 .users_list_item.xml with no background color.

I spent whole day in solving this problem ...help me with this..thank you...

Comment: You need to write a custom `Adapter` or extend `ArrayAdapter` to implement this functionality.

Comment: But I would worry about other things first. There are many isssues in your code. Some are just about coding conventions, but others can be a real problem.

Comment: What are the issues ???

Comment: how to do with extending ArrayAdapter...can you edit my class and post it here..please..i am beginner to android i am trying my best to understand things...

Comment: For example: You have a Method called `setComversationList()` which is anything but a setter

Comment: You don't use `Fragments` and you use `System.out.println()` to log.

Comment: You register a `BroadcastReceiver` possibly multiple times in a Method called `showSpinner()` but you never even once seem to unregister it again.

Comment: And no, I am not just going to edit your class and do your work for you. Instead you should go through this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: okay i will try this...its eating my head...hope i will complete this one today..

Comment: Or even better yet, don't use a `ListView` at all and instead switch to the new `RecyclerView`. You can learn how to use the `RecyclerView` here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#RecyclerView

Answer (score -1):

To solve your problem follow this steps.

1. Create your own custom adapter, you take help from [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown).
2. In custom adapter get reference of the particular list item and change its background accordingly.